# Is there a way to bind static .a ios libraries with different architectures, without creating a single fat library?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I need to bind a static library with Xamarin iOS, that I have as two files, each for a different architecture (arm64 and x86_64).

Is there a way to make an automatic build for each architecture, without needing to bind a fat library but this two libraries separately? (to minimize the app size)

Currently I'm copy pasting the different binaries for different builds... that feels silly.

Anyone suggestions?

Comment: Hi, whether this be helpful? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=windows#creating-a-static-library

Comment: @JuniorJiang tnx, this doesn't show how to bind different architecture libs without creating a fat library. 
In the end I justed created a fat library with 2 architectures.